# border-bottom CSS rule won't transition on mouseoff but will on hover

Tags: html, css

When I try to apply a transition for when you mouseon and mouseoff a nav item the item only uses the transition for mouseon, not mouseoff.

https://jsfiddle.net/grflint2/hp4qfma5/
has the code for this. I am using `transition: border-color 0.1s, padding 0.1s;` on the `:hover` selector and the normal one, but it's still not working.

I want it to transition off the same way it does when you hover over it. Why isn't it doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incorrectly set the transition.  You used the word 'padding' instead of 'padding-bottom'.  Regardless, you can remove the names all together and put in 'all' instead, since they are timed the same.
So for example, you can change the lines where you have the following code

```
      transition: border-color 0.1s, padding 0.1s;
```

to this following code instead...(I slowed it down just so the change can be seen)

```
     transition: all .5s;
```

Answer (score 1):

changed your border in the initial state from

```
border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
```

to

```
border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/041qdh3b/)